# Trying to login to a website using casperjs. Submitting the form makes an ajax request

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, phantomjs, casperjs

The result of the capture gives me a picture of the login page with a progressing gif it doesn't show the picture of the dashboard or what ever the page that comes after login, which is what I want. I tried using all types of waitfor() but I failed.

```
var casper = require("casper").create({
    userAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/537.22 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/25.0.1364.172 Safari/537.22',
    pageSettings : {
        userAgent : "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36"
    },
    verbose : true,
    logLevel : "debug",
    clientScripts : ["jquery.js"]
})
var fs = require("fs");



casper.on("error", function(msg){
    this.echo("error: " + msg, "Error");
})
casper.on("page.error", function(msg, trace){
    this.echo("Page Error: " + msg, "error");
});
var alexa = "https://www.alexa.com/secure/login?resource=%2Fpro%2Fscreener";
var proScreener = "http://www.alexa.com/pro/screener"
var form = "form#ajax-login-form";
var submitButton = "input#submit";

casper.start(alexa, function(){
    casper.waitForSelector(form, function(){
        // var cookies = JSON.stringify(phantom.cookies);
        // fs.write("cookies.txt", cookies, 644);
        console.log("form found!!");
    })
});
casper.then(function(){
    casper.sendKeys('input[id="email"]', "hiding.com");
    casper.sendKeys('input[id="pwd"]', "hidingPass");
    casper.click(submitButton);

})
casper.then(function(){
    this.capture("Afterlogin.png");
    // this.waitFor(function check(){
    //     return this.evaluate(function(){
    //         return document.querySelectorAll(".profile.popped").length
    //     });
    // }, function then(){
    //     this.captureSelector("selector.png",".profile.popped" )
    // })
})
```

In the command promp:

```
[info] [phantom] Step _step 3/5: done in 36592ms.
[info] [phantom] waitFor() finished in 40ms.
[info] [phantom] Step anonymous 4/6 https://www.alexa.com/secure/login?resource=
/pro/screener (HTTP 200)
form found!!
[info] [phantom] Step anonymous 4/6: done in 36666ms.
[info] [phantom] Step anonymous 5/6 https://www.alexa.com/secure/login?resource=
/pro/screener (HTTP 200)
[debug] [phantom] Mouse event 'mousedown' on selector: input[id="email"]
[debug] [phantom] Mouse event 'mouseup' on selector: input[id="email"]
[debug] [phantom] Mouse event 'click' on selector: input[id="email"]
[debug] [phantom] Mouse event 'mousedown' on selector: input[id="pwd"]
[debug] [phantom] Mouse event 'mouseup' on selector: input[id="pwd"]
[debug] [phantom] Mouse event 'click' on selector: input[id="pwd"]
[debug] [phantom] Mouse event 'mousedown' on selector: input#submit
[debug] [phantom] Mouse event 'mouseup' on selector: input#submit
[debug] [phantom] Mouse event 'click' on selector: input#submit
[info] [phantom] Step anonymous 5/6: done in 36844ms.
[info] [phantom] Step anonymous 6/6 https://www.alexa.com/secure/login?resource=
/pro/screener (HTTP 200)
[debug] [phantom] Capturing page to C:/Users/jack/Desktop/node-working/casperpra
c3/Afterlogin.png
[info] [phantom] Capture saved to C:/Users/jack/Desktop/node-working/casperprac3
/Afterlogin.png
[info] [phantom] Step anonymous 6/6: done in 36994ms.
[info] [phantom] Done 6 steps in 36999ms
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=about:blank, type=Other, willNavigat
e=true, isMainFrame=true
[debug] [phantom] url changed to "about:blank"
```

Comment: Not familiar with casper, but... Have you tried using `waitForSelector` to wait for something that's only on the dashboard? If you want the same page every time, you could also navigate directly to its URL after logging in.